# working mail system (real users) switch to virtual users Postfix+Dovecot+Roundcube Debian Wheezy

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, debian-wheezy

I have a working configuration on a `Debian Wheezy` VPS of:

- postfix 2.9.6
- dovecot 2.1.7 (imap and pop3 but only use imap)
- roundcube 0.9.5

This is using real `mailboxes` (i.e. my linux users/passwords) and `TLS encryption` (SASL is the package for that, right?) with site SSL certificates (not CA certified) and is using a single domain.

It all works great.  It took me a decent amount of time to get this set up with my primary domain and I am happy with it.  I don't want to screw it up.

I need to add 1-3 new domains that I am going to host on the box.  I am fine with the web site aspect of this but I am not sure about the email part.

I assume I will need (want?) to switch from Linux users to virtual users and virtual domains (stored in mySQL, I don't want to mess with LDAP just now... or do I?).

Most of the resources I find are about setting up a mail system from scratch using virtual users or real users.  I have not found a good resource that talks of migrating a working config from real to virtual.

1. Can my primary domain stay using the working setup and just service the new domains with virtual?
2. If no, does anyone have experience with this scenario? Any resources you can point to for help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change the settings to virtual users. When we join the virual users and normal users there may be a chance of conjunction between them. So i prefer to use the virual users only.

You can read more about the virtual users and virtual domains from this [link](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) 
If you want to implement this using mysql refer this [link](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-debian-wheezy)